# Get Calendar data from BambooHR

Tags: sharepoint, integration, bamboo, spfx

I am using SharePoint Online. I have created an SPFx react solution for custom development.

I have integrated the [Full Calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react) component under that solution.

I need to get employee time off, birthday, and anniversary data from BambooHR and show that in the calendar.

I can view the calendar using the below link,
https://contoso.bamboohr.com/calendar

I have found below API link from the BambooHR site,

https://documentation.bamboohr.com/reference/get-employees-directory-1

There is no API method for getting calendar data.

Can anyone help me with the same?